# After Windows/BIOS update, GRUB boot option gone and I can't boot to LiveUSB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am running a dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.X on an ASUS Zenbook UX330U. After a Windows and possibly BIOS update yesterday, the option to dual boot is missing.

[BIOS Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/butMa.jpg)

I can only select Windows Boot Manager.  I recall having this problem before, and it was easily fixed by repairing GRUB using a LiveUSB.
However, I cannot get the LiveUSB to boot.  I disabled Fast Startup in Windows 10. I have disabled Fast Boot in the BIOS.  Legacy USB has been enabled. The CSM option is greyed out, and I cannot turn it on.

Further info from comment:

I didn't do anything. Both the Windows and the BIOS update seemed to occur automatically. The only reason I suspect a BIOS update is that my ASUS booted to the BIOS screen after the first update mandated reboot. Then it proceeded to Windows Boot manager, updated, and rebooted again. The next reboot went right to Windows, updated, the rebooted. This process repeated three or four times. When I couldn't boot to Linux, I checked the BIOS version number was 315. I don't recall what it was before

[Fast Boot Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMVeA.jpg)

[Legacy USB Support Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEGrM.jpg)

Any help getting a LiveUSB to boot so that I can repair my GRUB so that I can go back to using Ubuntu is greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you have in "Add boot options"?

Comment: @guillermo chamorro
Nothing under Add Boot Options (https://imgur.com/a/afXOW4y)

Comment: You can try a "dirty" workaround with EasyUEFI. Install in Windows and with that you should be able to create an entry for Ubuntu.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I will check it out!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm sorry, this is unclear at least to me. "Possible BIOS update"?  Where did you obtain the BIOS update for your ASUS Zenbook UX330U that may or may not have been applied? What instructions did you follow when/if you did so? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @Elder Geek  Honestly, I didn't do anything.  Both the Windows and the BIOS update seemed to occur automatically.  The only reason I suspect a BIOS update is that my ASUS booted to the BIOS screen after the first update mandated reboot.  Then it proceeded to Windows Boot manager, updated, and rebooted again.  The next reboot went right to Windows, updated, the rebooted. This process repeated three or four times.
When I couldn't boot to Linux, I checked the BIOS version number was 315.  I don't recall what it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.  When I was looking at the Security Page of the BIOS screen, I failed to notice the slider bar on the right.

[BIOS Screen With Slider Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4z16.jpg)

When I scrolled down lower using the slider bar, I found the Secure Boot option.

[Secure Boot Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRgct.jpg)

Under the Secure Boot option, I was able to disable [Secure Boot Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clH7R.jpg) which allowed me to boot from the USB.

As a follow on, I was unable to repair my GRUB.  I followed very explicit instructions, but apparently I was unsuccessful.  However, I was able to salvage all my data to an external hard drive, which in turn allowed me to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with an answer. Please remember to click the grey check mark next to the answer to let others know this is the proper solution. Thanks,

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Thank you!  Done.

Answer (score 0):

It's been reported that ASUS Live Update was [hacked.](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/asus-live-update-utility-software-hacked-update,38927.html) This may explain why the version of your BIOS is higher than the currently released version (305 at the moment).  I suggest that you  contact [ASUS support](https://www.asus.com/support/) and request assistance in determining whether your Live Update software was infected with malware and installing a supported BIOS on your system. ASUS has a diagnostic tool available [here.](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1039336/)

Comment: Yikes!  Thanks for the tip. I ran the analyzer and it said no infection.  But I am still calling ASUS support.  If nothing else, I will get them to walk me through the process for allowing booting from another source.
Thanks for the warning and advice!

Comment: Don't forget to mention the BIOS version. It's odd that it's showing 315 instead of 305. Without knowing the code involved with the diagnostic tool, that might possibly provide false results. Good luck!

Comment: By the way, The way we say thanks here is by upvoting/accepting (green check mark) answers that were most useful to us. If you haven't yet, you might like to take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour)

Comment: I did.  I got a message saying "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Ah, yes. Until your reputation reaches 15 you aren't allowed to vote at all. Only accept (via the green check mark) The list of priveleges and the reputation required for each can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the help!